# Push Data with API REST in Algolia

Tags: javascript, api, rest, algolia

I'm learning to use angolia, but I have a question about it. Is it possible to push data to an index with API REST?

I have only seen to use API CLIENT, installed for Javascript with npm, but I don't want to install it.

what I want it's something like that:

```
    curl -X POST 'https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query' \
  -H 'X-Algolia-Application-Id: YourApplicationId' \
  -H 'X-Algolia-API-Key: YourAPIKey' \
  --data '{"query": "Paris"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a RESTful API available, but [there is no SLA when using it directly](https://www.algolia.com/policies/sla/).

Here's an example:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "X-Algolia-API-Key: ${API_KEY}" \
     -H "X-Algolia-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
     --data-binary '{ "params": "query=Paris" }' \
     "https://${APPLICATION_ID}-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/${INDEX_NAME}/query"
```

[View the API documentation.](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#search-endpoints)